# Map multiple attributes to img tag in a FCE

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

I am developing a typo3 website with TemplaVoila.

I want to map image 'src' attribute and 'alt' attribute to a image tag in My FCE. I tried to map by keeping both src field(of Element Preset:image field) and alt field(of Element Preset:plain input text) as attributes.

But that gave me a wrong result. Markup of obtained result is:

```
      <img src="&lt;img src=" typo3temp="" pics="" 2a0197a437.jpg"="" width="200" height="113" alt> "" alt="alternate text" />;
```

How to map this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it... :)
Map the img tag to a container field and add src, alt fields under it as attribute field and map it.